# "A non well formed numeric value encountered" after publish my cms

Tags: php, laravel, date

I made simple cms on Laravel and in one view i wanted compute current age of actor. So into view I have:

```
{{date('Y-m-d') - $actor->DOB}} years old
```

On localhost it works correctly but after share website I have this error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Comment: Doesn't `date('Y-m-d')` return a string? You can't subtract from a string.

Comment: You can possibly do this: `{{explode("-",date('Y-m-d'))[0] - explode("-",$actor->DOB)[0]}} years old` since you only need the years anyways. But it's not a good solution. Or actually... `{{date('Y') - explode("-",$actor->DOB)[0]}} years old`

Comment: Your question should include what the variable is for us to properly help you.

Comment: It works of course but this way it doesn't exact. So it doesn't matter whether actor was born on january or december. We shall take into account only year.

Comment: Include what the values are of your variable and we can help you. If you don't then it's just another poor formulated question that should be closed and deleted.

Comment: You shouldn't be performing arithmetic on a string. The `DateTime` class and `Carbon` package available within Laravel will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your local environment is different from your production environment.

But you should try and implement Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/

Instructions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

In your Actor model add the DOB field into the dates array:

```
class Actor extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['DOB'];
}
```

Comment: I used Carbon with other controller but I don't think that it's the best way. In next step I want to display age of actors with every single film. So compute age into view is better, I think.

Comment: @kazuhiro87 this is your answer. You want to use Carbon or DateTime for what you're doing. `$actor->DOB->diffInYears(Carbon::now())`